# Labeling part of an equation

Tags: cross-referencing

How do I label part of an equation using the same counter as for equations? For example,

```
\begin{align}
x^2+bx+c&=x^2+bx+\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{b^2}{4}+c \label{eq:1}\\
&=(x+b/2)^2+\underbrace{(-\frac{b^2}{4}+c)}{(*)} \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
The quantity~\ref{eq:2}...
```

produces

[image: labeling]

But I want the (2) to appear where the (*) is. (I.e., I want to use the equation counter but place the label in an arbitrary location, which is under the underbrace here.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want `(2)` on the right most place?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't want (2) in the rightmost place, so Herbert's answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x^2+bx+c &= x^2+bx+\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{b^2}{4}+c \label{eq:1}\\
           &= (x+b/2)^2+\underbrace{(-\frac{b^2}{4}+c)}_{%
             \stepcounter{equation}\mbox{(\theequation)}} \nonumber
\end{align}
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:2}

The quantity~\ref{eq:2}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\myeqno{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\theequation\addtocounter{equation}{-1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
x^2+bx+c&=x^2+bx+\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{b^2}{4}+c \label{eq:1}\\
&=(x+b/2)^2+\underbrace{(-\frac{b^2}{4}+c)}_{%
             \displaystyle(\myeqno)} \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
The quantity~\ref{eq:2}...
\end{document}
```

[image]